# Use of Mixture of Static and Dynamic Shared Memory in Nested Arrays for Cuda Kernels

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I sometimes see the following shared memory declaration in CUDA kernels, and I am not sure what it means:

```cpp
extern __shared__ T shmem[][SZ]
```

with `SZ` being a compile-time constant. The kernel is launched as:

```
kernel<<<grid, block, shared_memory_size>>>()
```

My questions are:

- Why could it be useful to have a mixture of dynamic and static shared memory (apart from simplifying the programmer's address computations)?
- What is the total size of the shared memory buffer shmem? Is it `shared_memory_size * SZ`?
- Related to Q2: Suppose I can compute shared_memory_size at compile time how would I have to rewrite the shared memory declaration for it to be static? `shared T shmem[SZ*shared_memory_size]`?

Comment: I’m pretty confident that the declaration you show in your question  isn't in any real code. And I don’t see any “static” “shared” memory anywhere in your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `__extern__ shared T shmem[][SZ]`

The proper syntax is

```cpp
extern __shared__ T shmem[][SZ];
```

> Why could it be useful to have a mixture of dynamic and static shared memory (apart from simplifying the programmer's address computations)?

I believe address computation is the only reason. Of course this also factors into static analysis etc. but that's really all that it is; making your work easier.

Of course if you make `SZ` a runtime variable even though it could be compile time, then the computational cost also goes up because then the GPU has to do proper integer multiplication for its address generation instead of optimizing it into cheaper operations such as bit shifts.

> What is the total size of the shared memory buffer shmem? Is it `shared_memory_size * SZ`?

No, the kernel launch parameter is in bytes. So the size along the outer dimension would be `shared_memory_size / (SZ * sizeof(T))`. To put it the other way around, if you want `shmem[N][SZ]` at runtime, then `shared_memory_size = N * SZ * sizeof(T)`

> Suppose I can compute `shared_memory_size` at compile time how would I have to rewrite the shared memory declaration for it to be static? `shared T shmem[SZ*shared_memory_size]`?

You mean like this?

```cpp
__shared__ T shmem[N][SZ];
```

Note how it is no longer declared `extern`.

Footnote: In terms of nomenclature I would not call this mixing static and dynamic shared memory. I believe most people would interpret mixing as using `__shared__ T` and `extern __shared__ T` in the same kernel.